# performance degradation after 30-40 mins c#

Tags: c#, web-services, download, webservice-client

I'm trying to download files from a remote location. But right before the download, I get my file locations from a web service, also on a remote location.

The thing is, I get a degrading performance over time. The downloaded file numbers decrease from around 2k in 3 minutes to 300-400 in the same time after an hour or two and I have 250k files.

Is the service or the download a problem? Or both?

I download files as below after I get the names from the service,

```
try
{
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
     if (File.Exists(filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext))
     {
        return "File Exists: " + filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext;
     }
     client.DownloadFile(virtualPath, filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext);
     return "Downloaded: " + filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext;
   }
 }
 catch (Exception e)  {
      return"Problem Downloading " + fileName + ": " + e.Message;
 }
```

Comment: Impossible to answer. We need more information what's going on.

Comment: but the good news is: with what you've written so far, it shouldn't be too hard to write away some sort of logging for both that will allow you to be sure.

Comment: `Path.Combine` is your friend: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx

Comment: You have to profile your application and check which part takes so long.

Comment: What should I log for? I am prepared to write a new application just to log if necessary.:)

Comment: Just try and pinpoint the part of the code that is increasingly taking longer to complete. FInding it should be fairly straightforward.

Comment: For download heavy tasks, I gave up on HttpWebRequest (and its various wrappers, WebClient, HttpClient etc) because I too have experienced inexplicable performance degradation. OTOH writing your own http protocol handler isn't the funnest of jobs, so I hope you get to the bottom of this. I'll be watching.

Comment: I will start profiling right after the application finishes.

Comment: How is your network routing/switching equipment holding out? Is it up to the job? Are you sure you're not overloading it?

Comment: @spender The problem it seems, is 2 fold. first is the info I displayed just for user information. The constant data flooding the richTextBox and the single line current status filling Label apparently was too much of a burden. So the first bottleneck is that the app tried to write all of those informative texts to various UI components. Removing them all helped to 1k downloads per minute. The next part I will need to do a little bit more research. There is still the degradation to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the information put on the **richTextBox** and **label**.

The rtb was appended with info regarding whatever happened to each individual element. The Label showed at which element we were. Apparently the cpu can't handle it and this becomes a major problem when running for prolonged time. It ate so much cpu that it eventually killed the application. Removing or limiting their output solved almost all problems.

On the other hand, the slight degradation (**1.5k** to **1.2k** ***per minute*** after **2.5 hours**) of the download that still exists is still a mystery.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (File.Exists(filePath + "/" + fileName + "." + ext))
```

Bottleneck is probably here.
When you get hella tons of files in a single folder checking if file with this name already exists might need some time to complete.
So you might want to store files in different folders

Comment: Just to make sure that problem is here: try to profile execution time for this method

Comment: Will start profiling to see what happens. Interesting idea though.

Comment: Indeed, that's a good place to start. And the solution is simple: Simply try to download the file. If it already exists it should throw an exception (Verify that it really is the case). Catch that. Why? Because that the file already exists should be an *exceptional* case.

Comment: Don't you think the disk can handle 10 file operations per second? This does not sound like it is the problem. I think the problem is not shown in the code posted.

Comment: try to find file in a folder, containing 5 files and in folder, containing 250k files, it's definitely taking more then 10 iops

Comment: Profiling does help indeed. @usr you sir, are correct but you will not guess what was the problem.

Comment: @sergio even windows has difficulty handling the files but It would be difficult to manage If I were to move to different folders.